# ObjectListView items invisible?

Tags: c#, winforms

For some reason I can't get any items to show up in an ObjectListView.
I created an ObjectListView, set the view to "Details" and added three columns, each with text and header. I then used this code to (try to) add items:

```
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
list.Add(new string[] { "col1", "col2", "col3" });
list.Add(new string[] { "col1", "col2", "col3" });

releases_ListView.AddObjects(list);
```

When I try `releases_ListView.Items.Count` I get '2' so the items are added to the collection, but for some reason the control itself remains empty. I also played around with enabling/disabling sorting/grouping and using `Refresh()` or `Update()` but with any result...

Nobody knows this? BTW, the items are definitely added. I get a selection box when I select the first rows, just no visible text.

Comment: what platform are you working with? wpf? silverlight? console? asp.net? winforms? (etc.)

Comment: @Muad'Dib I'm using winforms (in visual c# express). @Joe Tuskan Yeah, I tried `SetObjects` but it has the same result.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably past when it would be helpful for the original poster but I had the same issue and was going crazy.

Where you need to put the name of the column (public property of the object which is used to build the column's data) is not in the `NAME` field and not in the `TEXT` field. I too could see the rows of data in the `ObjectListView` control though the rendered control was just column headers and blank rows. No amount of invalidating, refreshing, or other manipulations could produce the data on the rendered form.

So... found out that if you put the name in the `AspectName` field on the `Columns Collection` through the IDE's `Columns Collection Editor`, then voila.... the data shows up in the control! There is likely a way to do it through a program but I leave that up to the next person since it's now doing what I needed.

Comment: WOW... I was struggling for a couple of hours and this helped upvote for you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Also unlikely to help the OP but another post for future passers by:

I have found the hands down best way to do this programmatically is using the OLVColumn attributes on your model class.

For example, take the following class:

```
public class ModelClass
{
    [OLVColumn(isVisible=false)]
    public string Id {get;set;}

    [OLVColumn()]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [OLVColumn()]
    public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

When the columns are generated by the form/view using the following line of code any property marked with the OLVColumn() attribute will be added as a column.

```
Generator.GenerateColumns(this.objectListView1,typeof(ModelClass));
```

You can also use this statement to just generate a column for every property on the class:

```
Generator.GenerateColumns(this.objectListView1, typeof(ModelClass), true);
```

The OP's original behaviour - having nothing show up in the ObjectListView when the items collection contains items - is due to the ObjectListView not having any columns assigned either at design time using AspectName as ToniMarieM stated, or failing to include the OLVColumn attribute if you are using the generator. This also happens if you use the second generator example and pass false as the third parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue... turns out the solution is to rebuild the columns after adding/removing them by calling RebuildColumns():

```
var folv = new FastObjectListView()
{
    AllColumns = new List<OLVColumn>()
    {
        new OLVColumn("Name", "Name")
        {
            IsVisible = true,
            ShowTextInHeader = true
        }
        // Add other columns here...
    },
    HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.Clickable,
    View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details
};
folv.RebuildColumns();
// ObjectListView is now ready!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing is that you can not add items in that way to `ListView` in `Detail` state.

You can do the following:

use [ListViewItem.SubItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems.aspx) property to ad "col2" and "col3" to every subitem of "col1"

In the link you can see an example how can you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another caveat.

If you are adding ObjectListView dynamically to a dynamically created tab in a tabControl you see the behavior explained in the question.

The solution is to select the newly created tab and THEN create the ObjectListView and add it to the tab page.

```
ctrlTabLogFiles.TabPages.Add(key, name);
var tab = ctrlTabLogFiles.TabPages[key];
ctrlTabLogFiles.SelectedTab = tab;
var gridCtrl = new GridWrapperControl();
tab.Controls.Add(gridCtrl);
```

And after this you can add your headers and data as before.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer way after the fact for the purposes of maybe helping someone else...

I had a class that was added to a solution by someone else at some point.  I was tasked with displaying a list of items of that type in an ObjectListView.  No matter what I tried with a new OLV on the form, I couldn't get anything to display.  I turned on alternating row colors to see if anything was showing up, and I was getting alternating rows for exactly how many objects were in the list.  I checked the objects in the OLV, and there were the correct numbers.  They just wouldn't display any text in the OLV.

After looking at the class for the millionth time, I realized the properties I was trying to display both had the internal access modifier.  I changed those to public and was able to get everything to show up.  For whatever reason, someone had set **only** those two properties to internal, and they ended up being the only two I was trying to display.

It was so obvious that I kept skipping over the answer.  Every other property in that class was public, so I didn't even bother to specifically check the ones I was using.  Every search I did brought up this question on SO, so I thought it would be worth sharing.  Hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Since I spent so much time on this issue, I'll add an answer for the mistake I made so that others can learn from it.

There was an errant call to `objlstview.BeginUpdate()` which was never closed by a `objlstview.EndUpdate()`. Therefore, whatever you do, the ObjectListView will never display your data.